# Interpreting negative interaction effect in regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction

I am running a multiple regression in order to understand effect of advertising spend on number of orders we generate. I am particularly interested in impact of TV spend. Below is my model with co-efficients
[image]

One of the things I found is there a co-relation between TV spend and Branded Search spend. And my assumption is that as you spend more on TV , more people will search you online by your brand name. In the previous model TV is barely significant. In the next model I tried the interaction effect of TV spend with Branded SEM spend and the results are below.

[image]

Trying to understand how suddenly TV spend is so significant and why the interaction has negative co-efficient even though both TV and Brand SEM spend are co-related.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the answer but a few thoughts that come to mind. How correlated are TV_spend and SEM_send, if the variables are highly correlated it might be that the model is having a hard time distinguishing between the two variables. Also although the interaction maybe "significant" is it meaningful ? Looking at the coefficient it appears to be quite small (to the power -4) does it have much of an impact in terms of predictions ?  EDIT - perhaps it is capturing part of a non-linear effect in your data - I can imagine TVspend doesn't result in a linear increase orders?

Comment: TV_spend and Brand_SEM_Spend has a co-relation of .26. It used to be close to .5 but I realize that I have made some changes to the raw data and that shows a lesser co-relation.  The interaction co-efficient is low but i am guessing the impact is good enough cause if I am spending 100 in TV and 100 in Bran SEM then the interaction will be multiplied by 10,000 which makes the interaction big enough.

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour doesn't seem related to correlation between predictors. It seems more related to the actual behaviour of your data.

Positive TVspend parameter means that -being all other variables equal- orders grow when TVspend grows. However, negative interaction means that when Brand_SEM_spend is larger, orders grow less with TVspend than when Brand_SEM_spend is smaller. In fact, depending on the range of your variables, it might even mean that orders *decrease* with TVspend when Brand_SEM_spend is large.

When you don't take on account Brand_SEM_spend, your model assumes that -being all other variables equal- the effect of TVspend is the same for all values of Brand_SEM_spend. Therefore, you are adjusting a single coefficient that account for TVspend efect, and that effect is actually different for different values of Brand_SEM_spend, so data is somehow conflicting and the parameter is adjusted to the "average" effect but with a large standard error. Since standard error is larger and parameter is smaller, it becomes less significant.

Just for illustration, I build a simple model that shows the same phenomenon.

Let's start with data generation:

```
> response<-function(tv,nobrand){.5*tv+5*nobrand-1*tv*nobrand}
> tv<-runif(100,0,1)
> nobrand<-runif(100,0,1)
> orders<-response(tv,nobrand)+.1*rnorm(100)
```

Please notice that since $tv$ is uniformly distributed in the range (0,1), its average effect is zero, although its parameter would be 0.5 when $nobrand=0$ and -0.5 when $nobrand=1$.

Adjusting a model without interaction shows that $tv$ has a parameter close to zero an not significant, as expected:

```
> summary(lm(orders~tv+nobrand))

Call:
lm(formula = orders ~ tv + nobrand)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.34751 -0.08337 -0.01841  0.09197  0.36638 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.22584    0.03600   6.274 9.84e-09 ***
tv           0.05138    0.04598   1.117    0.267    
nobrand      4.51445    0.04759  94.864  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1451 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9893,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9891 
F-statistic:  4504 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

However, adjusting a model with interaction shows clearly significant $tv$ effect and interaction, that is, it shows that $tv$ has an effect but this effect depends on $nobrand$:

```
> summary(lm(orders~tv*nobrand))

Call:
lm(formula = orders ~ tv * nobrand)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.198747 -0.068419 -0.009158  0.068185  0.258584 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.02989    0.03612  -0.828     0.41    
tv           0.56321    0.06080   9.263 5.69e-15 ***
nobrand      5.02382    0.06120  82.083  < 2e-16 ***
tv:nobrand  -1.03896    0.10440  -9.952  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1023 on 96 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9948,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9946 
F-statistic:  6070 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Interestingly, both in your data and my simulation R-adjusted and all p-values are larger when the interaction is included, supporting that interaction should be included in the model.

Comment: Thanks. Its really helpful in understanding the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be running multiple regression if your response variable is categorical. This is because by fitting this model, you are assuming that that response variable is conditionally Normally distributed. A Normal random variable is a continuous random variable, so this does not work.

Try Poisson regression or zero-inflated Poisson regression. In `R` you could use the functions `glm` and `zeroinfl` for these tasks. Perhaps you will get parameter estimates that cohere better with your beliefs. If I could see your data I could tell you more.